# decoding json in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

my json is below. What i'm trying to do is access column but I'm getting lowerdeck as undefined. Please help me solve this.

```
{
  "errorcode": "0",
  "xml": {
    "seat-map": {
      "lower-deck": {
        "column": [
          {
            "$": {
              "id": "1"
            },
            "row": [
              {
                "$": {
                  "id": "1"
                },
                "seat": {
                  "$": {
                    "number": "3",
                    "status": "0"
                  }
                }
              },

              {
                "$": {
                  "id": "12"
                },
                "seat": {
                  "$": {
                    "number": "#",
                    "status": "blank"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i have done

```
if (!err && seatmap) {
       var obj = seatmap;
       var seatmap = 'seat-map';
         var lowerdeck = 'lower-deck';

     console.log('seat map '+ obj.xml.seatmap.lowerdeck);

        res.send(seatmap);
```

but I'm getting cannot read lowerdeck, I need to access column.

and yes i have too many codes in my questions, can't i have it like that , ofcourse mypost is mostly code. stupid stackflow !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the hyphenated names in brackets, like this:

```
seatmap.xml['seat-map']['lower-deck'].column
```

For consistency, you could also just put all the names in brackets:

```
seatmap['xml']['seat-map']['lower-deck']['column']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use seatmap['lower-deck'] to access that property.